# Get custom post type by ID in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm basically looking at somehow creating a loop so I can show the content of a single custom post type based on it's ID.

So, I want to get the content from the custom post type with an ID of 3788.

There is a function in there to get the featured image URL too.

For example, here's my code at the moment:

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'about', 'posts_per_page' => 1 ); ?>

<?php $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<?php global $post; ?>
<?php
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' ); ?>  
<div class="section" style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?>) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; z-index:-1;">

<?php the_content () ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Whats your problem? What line of code didn't work for you?

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work, it's that it doesn't do what I need. I need to pull a single post from 'about', not every post from there.

Comment: Are you talking about post category 'about' or did you create a custom post type 'about' for the dashboard?

Comment: Just go ahead and create template `single-about.php` and just run the basic `while` loop without any `wp_query` you will get your content, images like other single pages.

Comment: I created a post type for the dashboard. I know how to pull every post from the custom post type, I'm trying to get the content from one post inside 'about'. For example, there are two posts in there with the IDs 3788 & 3799. I just want the content from post 3788.

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php 
$ID = 3788;
$args = array('p' => $ID, 'post_type' => 'about');
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <?php global $post; ?>
    <?php
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ),  false, '' ); ?>  
    <div class="section" style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?>) no-repeat center     center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; z-index:-1;">
    <?php the_content () ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting an error on line 5, I tried ?> after $loop = new WP_Query($args); but it still didn't work.

Comment: I edited that mistake, and the code is working for me - are you sure all other PHP tags are closed properly?

Comment: I tried the code, and whilst I'm not getting any errors, it is coming up blank. The ID is correct, do I need to put the ID anywhere else?

Comment: How are you getting the post ID?  Make sure that's correct, and also see my edit where I add post type to $args.

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?php
   $ids= array(3788); // for example, You can also pass multiple IDs in array
   $args = array('post_type' => 'about','post__in' => $ids);
   $loop = get_posts($args);
   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
   global $post;

   $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 
   5600,1000 ), false, '' ); ?>  
   <div class="section" style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?>) no- 
   repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background- 
   size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover; z-index:-1;">
   <?php the_content () ?>

   <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this question and wants an easy way to to do this, [get_post_field](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_field/) is the function you are looking for.  Say you have a post with an ID of 420.  If you just want to get the post content for that post regardless of if you are in the loop or not, you could do:

```
<?php echo get_post_field( 'post_content', 420); ?>
```

I like doing it this way in some cases because it is just one line of code.  You can do this for any of the [fields that are included in a post object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/#comment-876) (*post_title, post_excerpt, post_type, post_author, post_parent etc*).

Now of course in your specific case you could have just done

```
<?php echo get_the_content( $post->ID ); ?>
```

But for those people with bad memory who can't remember all the functions like get_the_content(), get_the_title(), get_the_author(), get_the_modified_date() etc, you have a one liner that will do it all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
'p' => $id_post, 
'post_type' => 'about', 
'post_status' => 'any, auto-draft','posts_per_page' => -1);
            $posts = get_posts($args);

            var_dump($posts);
```

You will not see the posts if they are in Draft or Trash so try to add post_status to your query args...took me while to notice that